# AWS Log Insights query with string contains

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

how do I query with contains string in AWS Log insights

```
fields @timestamp, @message
filter @message = "user not found"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20

fields @timestamp, @message
filter @message strcontains("User not found")
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Answer (score 218, accepted):

This should work fine

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /user not found/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Comment: For clarity, the forward-slashes encase the string you're searching for. For instance, I was looking for HTTP 500 errors, so my string looked like: `| filter @message like / 500 /`

Answer (score 37):

I recently ran into the same scenario. strcontains takes the input string as the first argument and the search value as the second. so in your case the following should work fine.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter strcontains(@message, "User not found")
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Comment: This is perfect when you don't want to escape a regex.

Answer (score 28):

I think you need to select them as fields and then filter on their value. e.g:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, strcontains(@message, "user not found") AS unf
| filter unf=1
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Or use regex

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /User\snot\sfound/
| ...
```

(haven't tested them)

Answer (score 17):

I was looking for *contains* and *in* filters. Allowed filtering options are:

```
'in', 'and', 'or', 'not', 'like', '=~', '~=', '|', '|>', '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '=', '!='
```

So the solution using *like* seems also the optimal version in terms of operator.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /user not found/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Nevertheless there's another possibility to parse the message itself and do an equal comparison for use cases where one needs to be more exact. For formatted log rows like:

```
2020-12-24T19:08:18.180+01:00 [main] INFO com.foo.bar.FooBar - My log message!
```

You can parse substrings from the message and assign them to a field which can then be filtered using *equal* operator ("="). In the example below you can see no "INFO" String in the message can interfere with filtering severity:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message "[*] * *" as @level, @severity, @info
| filter @logStream like "my/stream/within/loggroup"
| filter @severity="INFO"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Comment: Nice post! Is there a way to have OR expression for the "like" operator? ex.: "filter message like /aaa/ or message like /bbb/ " or "filter message in like ("aaa", "bbb") ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Here‘s some good examples what you can do from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-examples.html

Answer (score 8):

Different ways to check if message contains substring/text in AWS Log Insights

###### 1. Using `LIKE` clause([Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-examples.html))

```sql
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /user not found/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

###### 2. Using `strcontains` string method([Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-string-functions.html))

```sql
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter strcontains(@message, "User not found")
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

###### 3. Using regex string method

```sql
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message =~ /.*User not found.*/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS is leveraging Generative AI to create your filters. Now you can describe what you need and it will create the filter for you.

1. Click on "Query generator"
2. Describe your filter

[image]